# Alter Ubercart Billing/Delivery Panes with User Profile Info

Tags: 7, users, ubercart, forms

I'm trying to set a user's profile fields into the checkout process. A user must change these data only in own profile. The [uc_addresses](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_addresses) module is unsuitable for my needs. In the order form I need to hide these fields.

Right now I'm using `uc_cart_checkout_form_alter` to do this:

```
function my_module_form_uc_cart_checkout_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
        // load user data
        global $user;

        $user_fields =user_load($user->uid);

        $first_name   = $user_fields->field_name['und']['0']['value'];

        // add data to order form
        $form['panes']['delivery']['delivery_first_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $first_name;
}
```

But default value isn't there. Where did I go wrong? How can I fill out an order form (Delivery & Billing information) programmatically in Ubercart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The billing/delivery address panes are [driven](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ubercart/tree/uc_cart/uc_cart_checkout_pane.inc#n244) by a custom `uc_address` form field. You need to alter it's `#default_value` object to alter the fields.

For example:

```
$form['panes']['delivery']['address']['#default_value']->delivery_first_name = $user_fields->field_name['und']['0']['value'];
$form['panes']['billing']['address']['#default_value']->billing_first_name = $user_fields->field_name['und']['0']['value'];
```